# How do I disable Blogs in mysites

Tags: sharepoint-online, my-site, blog

I have a SharePoint Online instance and want to disable blogs for my users.
I can't seem to find a setting for this anywhere in SharePoint Online.
Any guidance on this would help.

If it is not possible to disable the feature, is there a method to hide the Blog option?
I have hidden this on the My Sites master page but it is still available through Site Contents.

Comment: Just to clarify, the environment I am speaking about is SharePoint Online 2013. This is running on an E3 license.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to Central Admin in your SharePoint online?

Depending of the plan you paid for you will have CA or not

[image: SP online Plans]

If you have it go to CA --> Manage Web Applications --> select mysite Web App --> General Settings --> Blog API Settings Section select no.

Try if this helps. If not a rudimentary way is to add a .js in MySiteHost Style Library with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#createnewsite').hide();
});
```

With this code you will hide de New Site button in site contents but anyone with firebug and a little bit of knowledge about javascript or knowing the URL _layouts/15/newsbweb.aspx will bypass this.

Hope it helps

---

Comment: I have an E3 license, but I can't find the option `CA --> Manage Web Applications `

Comment: When I go to Admin>SharePoint>user profiles I do find `My Site Settings` but that doesn't allow me to turn of blogs.

Comment: Because that option is in web application settings not in my site settings within the user profile service app. On premise is easy to do but I have no online demo to test.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that is possible.  It's part of the My Site template.  What @Alvmad is proposing is simply to disable the API to blog sites.  That will prevent tools like Windows Live Writer from connecting to the blog but not disable the blog itself.

This is true for on premise solutions as well.  Typically here to modify a my site you would look to a method called feature stapling. That method is not valid on O365.  The closes thing I can think of is publishing a custom app to the catalog and pushing that out, and have that deploy some custom CSS file that could the links directly to the blogs. I have not tried anything like this and outside of this - there is probably no automatic way to do so.